# Erro ao cadastrar usuário em Django

Tags: django

Quando desejo cadastrar um novo usuário em Django, recebo o seguinte aviso: 
`UNIQUE constraint failed: polls_usuario.matriculaUsuario`

O que pode estar acontecendo?

**views.py**

```
def registrar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and usuario_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.usuario.matriculaUsuario = form.cleaned_data.get('matriculaUsuario')
            usuario_form.save()
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request,user)
            return render(request, 'polls/index.html', user)
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/')) 
            #return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/registrar.html', {'form': form , 'usuario_form':usuario_form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class UsuarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('matriculaUsuario',)

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Primeiro Nome',max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Opcional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Último Nome',max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Opcional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail',max_length=254, help_text='Informe o seu e-mail (Requerido)')   
    username = forms.CharField(label='Nome de usuário', min_length=4, max_length=150)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Senha', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirmação da senha', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    matriculaUsuario = forms.CharField(label='Matrícula',max_length=12,validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','username','matriculaUsuario','email','password1', 'password2',] 
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("Nome de usuário já cadastrado")
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("E-mail já cadastrado")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Senhas não conferem")

        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['username'],
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password1']
        )
        return user
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Nome')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Sobrenome')
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=150,help_text=("Insira um novo nome de usuário"), label='Nome de usuário')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail')
    matriculaUsuario = forms.CharField(label='Matrícula', max_length=12,validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))])
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name','username','matriculaUsuario','email']
```

**models.py**

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    matriculaUsuario = models.CharField(default='000000000000',max_length=12,primary_key=True,null=False,help_text=_('São requeridos os 12 dígitos referentes à sua matrícula'), validators=[ validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[0-9]{12}$'), _('Digite uma matrícula válida'), _('invalid'))])
    def __str__(self):
 return self.user.username
        @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_usuario(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Usuario.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.usuario.save()

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_usuario(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Usuario.objects.create(user=instance)
    post_save.connect(create_user_usuario,sender=User)
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_usuario(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
        if created:
            instance.usuario.save()
```

**EDIT**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A mensagem diz que vc esta tentando incluir um registro "repetido", em uma tabela cujo campo `matriculaUsuario` tem a restricao `UNIQUE`, traduzindo: vc esta tentando cadastrar um segundo aluno com o mesmo numero de matricula de um que ja existe na tabela, com restrição para isso.

Comment: @Sidon, no caso a matricula é para ser única entre os usuários. O que eu devo fazer para que não ocorra este erro? Pois só há o usuário admin no banco e a sua matrícula não é a mesma que está sendo cadastrada como teste.

Comment: Vc precisa checar antes de chamar o `save()`, sugiro fazer testes no shell do django para ter certeza que esta enviando os dados corretamente.

Comment: @Sidon, a saída do POST foi essa:                                              
first_name 
'Teste'
last_name 
'Teste'
username 
'teste'
matriculaUsuario 
'222222222222'
email 
'oioioi@oioioi.com'
password1 
'RSRSRSRS'
password2 
'RSRSRSRS'

Comment: Entre no admin do django e tente cadastrar alguns usuários por lá para ver o q acontece.

Comment: @Sidon, acontece o mesmo erro

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91729/discussion-between-murilo-de-jesus-and-sidon).

Comment: @Sidon, editei com a definição do usuário. Não estou conseguindo acessar o chat no momento

Comment: Ok, esta meio confuso, mas postei uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi que vc precisa apenas estender o `User` adicionando alguns campos, sem necessariamente mudar nada no `auth`, ou seja, vc não esta customizando a autenticação, correto? mas não consegui entender o que vc quis fazer no model `Usuario`, a meu ver deveria ser mais simples, ou vc realmente customiza tudo ou apenas estende a classe `User` embutida no django, vou dar um [exemplo da propria documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) (fazendo uma pequena adaptacao ao seu contexto, porém chamando o seu usario de Aluno) colocando a classe extendida no admin, coisa que vc não fez:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Aluno(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Adicionando os campos (adicione qtos precisar)
    matricula = models.CharField('Matrícula', max_length=12)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Aluno

class AlunoInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Aluno
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name = 'Informações Pessoais'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (AlunoInline,)

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

@admin.register(Aluno)
class AlunoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Aluno
    list_display = ('user', 'matricula',)
```

Pronto, agora vá no admin do django e vc terá:

[image: Admin djangoi]

Voce pode adiconar alunos (usuario) tanto pelo auth (AUTENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION) quanto pelo USERS (Alunos)

Embora repl.it ainda tem algumas limitacoes com o django, [deixei funcionando lá](https://extend-user1--sidonduarte.repl.co/admin/auth/user/add/), para rodar é preciso fazer um fork, migrations e criar o superuser (só seguir as instrucoes do painel CLI no lado inferior direito).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema: UNIQUE constraint failed: polls_aluno.user_id. O que pode ser? Já coloquei um valor default, mas não obtive êxito.

Comment: Como o django trabalha com muita abstracao é dificil entender o q vc esta querendo, sugiro que quebre o problema em pedacos menores, baseado na minha resposta, tente colocar o Usuario no admin, vc esta trabalhando direto com User. Outra coisa, olhe no banco de dados (para abrir o banco, se nao tem nada, tente o [dbeaver community](https://dbeaver.io/download/2/)) Veja o que ja tem cadastrado lá e veja se tem ujma pista do motivo dessa mensagem. Tb n entendi pq vc  os metodos `create_user_usuario` e `save_user_usuario`. Poderia explicar?

Comment: Tentei criar um novo banco, do zero, e o problema continua. Aparentemente, o meu problema está no campo unique. Copiei o seu código e quando fui fazer o makemigratios, o id , que seria a primary_key de aluno, deu erro por ser unique=True. Eu consigo colocar o usuário no Admin, o problema está no cadastro de um novo usuário somente. Quando vou editar posteriormente a sua matrícula, não ocorre erro.

Comment: Sobre os métodos  create_user_usuario e save_user_usuario, foram testes de pesquisa realizada na internet somente

Comment: Criei um novo projeto e o problema não ocorre mais. Será chato ter que populá-lo novamente, porém o importante é funcionar. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Sugiro que vc foque primeiramente em algo simples, use a estrutura da minha resposta, retire aqueles 2 metodos q vc colocou mas não sabe explicar.  Se eu tivesse que apontar uma coisa negativa no django seria o nível de abstração e, por causa disso, vc pode entrar em tremenda armadilha se ir enfiando codigo no seu sistema sem compreender profundamente o porque. O preço a pagar por isso no futuro é bem alto.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Sou novo em Django e estou começando a fazer o meu projeto final na faculdade, ainda estou um pouco perdido, mas agora irei focar na estrutura para depois popular o banco